# IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array

Tags: c#, unity3d

Делаю игру по этому туториалу: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R897fzBmZOU&list=PLRHtm1zQx-f_iPJNssrmZFSj9H5a00e5I&index=7
Когда игрок получает ключ выдает ошибку.

Вот полный текст ошибки:

IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
Quests.OnTriggerEnter2D (UnityEngine.Collider2D other) (at Assets/Scripts/Quests.cs:15)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Quests : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int questNumber;
    public int[] items;
    public GameObject[] clouds;
    public GameObject barrier;
    public GameObject key;

    public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if(other.tag != "Player" && other.gameObject.GetComponent<Pickup>().id == items[questNumber])
        {
            questNumber++;
            Destroy(other.gameObject);
            CheckQuest();
        }
    }

    public void CheckQuest()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < clouds.Length; i++)
        {
            if(i == questNumber)
            {
                clouds[i].SetActive(true);
                clouds[i].GetComponent<Animator>().SetTrigger("isTrigger");
            }
            else 
            {
                clouds[i].SetActive(false);
            }
        }
        if(questNumber == 3)
        {
            barrier.SetActive(false);
        }
        if(questNumber == 4)
        {
            key.SetActive(true);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Тебе же буквально пишет: Index was outside the bounds of the array. Индекс находится вне границ массива. Тебе же даже строчку в ошибке пишет где ошибка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо учиться писать код самостоятельно. Туториалы хороши, когда кроме бездумного копирования кода хотя-бы немного его понимаешь.

Индекс `questNumber` у вас имеет значение больше, чем количество элементов в массиве `items`. При попытке обратиться к несуществующему элементу массива возникает указанное исключение.

Обратите внимание, что в C# индексы массивов начинаются с 0, а не с 1. Например для массива из 3 элементов валидные индексы: 0, 1 и 2.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Пока искал как исправить ошибку уже сам немного понял смысл ошибки. Но до сих пор не могу понять как можно её исправить. Можете пожалуйста уточнить каким образом ее можно исправить.

Comment: @Михаил это уж вам виднее. Например вместо `questNumber++;` сделать `questNumber = (questNumber + 1) % items.Length;`